# mysql select if one-to-many exist

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, exists

how can i check if a many-to-one relations already exist?

```
SampleTable
╔════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ OB_ID ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║
║  1 ║     2 ║
║  2 ║     3 ║
║  2 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║     1 ║
║  3 ║     3 ║
╚════╩═══════╝
```

I want to search for SampleTable.ob_id and select SampleTable.id, if exist.

Search for (1,2) 
return 1;

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
╚════╝
```

search for (1,2,3)  
return 2;

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  2 ║
╚════╝
```

search for (2,3)  
return empty recordset (or null)

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╚════╝
```

Comment: input is ob_id, it can be a combination of any ob_id (two or more)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName a
WHERE ob_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) =
            (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM TableName b
              WHERE b.ID = a.ID
            ) AND
      COUNT(*) = 3 -- the value of this depend on the number of values
                   -- you have supplied on you where clause.
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo for values [1, 2]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42ba0/14)
- [SQLFiddle Demo for values [1, 2, 3]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42ba0/13)
- [SQLFiddle Demo for values [2, 3]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42ba0/15)

if unique constraint was not defined on `ob_ID` for every `ID`,  you need to use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName a
WHERE ob_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ob_id) =
            (
              SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ob_id)
              FROM TableName b
              WHERE b.ID = a.ID
            ) AND
      COUNT(DISTINCT ob_id) = 2
```

Comment: thanks! ob_id to id relation is unique; what about performance (100k rows or more) ?

Comment: if the table was correctly index then you don't have to worry on the performance.

Comment: I've this index: PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`ob_id`); ENGINE=MyISAM